# Setting href via jquery click event only fires once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery that changes the href attribute of an `<a>` tag, but it only runs once

This is what I have:

JS:

```
$('.swatch span').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var link = $(this).parents().attr("href");
      if($(this).data("image").indexOf("no-image") == -1) {
        $(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('img').attr('src', $(this).data("image"));
        $(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('img').attr('srcset', $(this).data("image"));
      }
      $(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('a').attr('href', link);
    });
```

[I found this answer and tried below:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194728/jquery-click-event-works-only-once)

```
$('.swatch span').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var link = $(this).parents().attr("href");
      if($(this).data("image").indexOf("no-image") == -1) {
        $(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('img').attr('src', $(this).data("image"));
        $(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('img').attr('srcset', $(this).data("image"));
      }
      $(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('a').attr('href', link);
    });
```

HTML/Markup:

```
<div class="one-third column alpha thumbnail even" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<!-- the link below needs to change -->
  <a href="/collections/polarized/products/product" itemprop="url">
    <div class="relative product--product collection--443303820 product_image">
      <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2321/4605/products/013_a-_g__72_380x@2x.jpg?v=1504208271" class="transition-in lazyloaded">

 <div class="collection_swatches">         
    <a href="/collections/polarized/products/product?variant=44459262348" class="swatch">
      <span data-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/7/2221/2305/products/store_013_a-_g__72_480x.jpg?v=1504208271" style="background-color: ; background-image: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/7/2221/2305/products/store_013_a-_g__72_480x.jpg?v=1504208271); background-position: center; background-size: contain"></span>
    </a>

    <a href="/collections/polarized/products/product?variant=44459262476" class="swatch">
      <span data-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/7/2221/2305/products/store_013_a-_b__72_480x.jpg?v=1504208271" style="background-color: ; background-image: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/7/2221/2305/products/store_013_a-_b__72_480x.jpg?v=1504208271); background-position: center; background-size: contain"></span>
    </a>

    <a href="/collections/polarized/products/product?variant=44459262668" class="swatch">
      <span data-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/7/2221/2305/products/_a-_g__72_480x.jpg?v=1504208271" style="background-color: ; background-image: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/7/2221/2305/products/store_003_a-_g__72_480x.jpg?v=1504208271); background-position: center; background-size: contain"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Doesn't work.

putting in `console.log('clicked')` returns `clicked` on every click.

1. why is my click event firing only once in both instances?
2. Does it have to do with the `.attr()` behavior? [I checked documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) but don't see anything that suggests that it only fires once.

Comment: Can you show your html? I don't think it only run once but rather everytime it runs it execute the exact same thing so you dont "feel" it's running. Have you tried `console.log('clicked')` to check?

Comment: Updated anaswer.

Comment: Also it's not an issue with the click event `console.log('clicked')` returns `clicked` in my console every click.

Comment: This code is wack. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @PHPglue I'm trying to change an attribute of a href with the link in the swatches using `.attr()` but it only fires once and I don't why. Also calling this "wack" isn't really productive for anyone involved I'm trying to work with an exisiting codebase and this is a part of it.

Comment: @kawnah,  since you have updated the HTML code in your answer, it is becoming more clear about what you want exactly to achieve, however, since you have not provided the location of closure tags of new HTML elements it is still ambiguous where to look for the elements, however try to inspect UPDATED answer

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('a').attr('href', link);`

will not lead to the link in html, since you do not have any thumbnail class in your html parents which are related to `this`, since `this` is  `a span` you have clicked on, or you need to add some elements with class `thumbnail`,

or try

`$(this).parents().find('a').attr('href', link);`

to get link you have clicked on use `parent()` instead of `parents()`:

```
var link = $(this).parent().attr("href");
```

when you add link to `parents()` that means that you changing all hrefs of all `a` elements, so when you click next time on any link, it will be always the one you have clicked first, so you need to specify where to apply clicked link exactly e.g. using only `$(this).parent().find('a').attr('href', link);`

p.s. in style setting `background: ;` is not the best thing to do, if you do not use one, just delete the rule ore use `background: none;`

**UPDATE**: now once you have updated the html, it is possible to see where `.thumbnail` element is located, however your new html elements in the answer are not closed, so I have guessed in order to make proper html code: see snipped below:

```js
$('.swatch span').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var link = $(this).parent().attr("href");
          if($(this).data("image").indexOf("no-image") == -1) {
            $(this).parents('.thumbnail').first().find('img').first().attr('src', $(this).data("image"));
            $(this).parents('.thumbnail').first().find('img').first().attr('srcset', $(this).data("image"));
          }
console.log(link);
        // update all a hrefs of all .thumbnail parents:
        //  $(this).parents().find('.thumbnail').find('a')[0]).attr('href', link);
          // update only the first a href of all .thumbnail parents
          $(this).parents('.thumbnail').first().find('a').first().attr('href', link);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="one-third column alpha thumbnail even" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<!-- the link below needs to change -->
  <a href="/collections/polarized/products/product" itemprop="url">
    <div class="relative product--product collection--443303820 product_image">
      <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2321/4605/products/013_a-_g__72_380x@2x.jpg?v=1504208271" class="transition-in lazyloaded">
    </div>
  </a>

 <div class="collection_swatches">         
    <a href="/collections/polarized/products/product?variant=44459262348" class="swatch">
      <span data-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/7/2221/2305/products/store_013_a-_g__72_480x.jpg?v=1504208271" style="background-color: ; background-image: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/7/2221/2305/products/store_013_a-_g__72_480x.jpg?v=1504208271); background-position: center; background-size: contain">link1</span>
    </a>

    <a href="/collections/polarized/products/product?variant=44459262476" class="swatch">
      <span data-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/7/2221/2305/products/store_013_a-_b__72_480x.jpg?v=1504208271" style="background-color: ; background-image: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/7/2221/2305/products/store_013_a-_b__72_480x.jpg?v=1504208271); background-position: center; background-size: contain">link2</span>
    </a>

    <a href="/collections/polarized/products/product?variant=44459262668" class="swatch">
      <span data-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/7/2221/2305/products/_a-_g__72_480x.jpg?v=1504208271" style="background-color: ; background-image: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/7/2221/2305/products/store_003_a-_g__72_480x.jpg?v=1504208271); background-position: center; background-size: contain">link3</span>
    </a>
 </div>

</div> <!-- .thumnail div closed here-->
```

Comment: It still has same behavior - it works *once* but then if I click on another swatch, it doesn't update.

Comment: @kawnah,  since you have updated the code in your  html, it is becoming more clear about what you want exactly to achieve, however, since you have not provided the location of closure tags of new html elements it is still ambiguous where to look for the elements, I have tryied to guess: play the snipped and inspect it to see if it is what you want to achieve, or provide the correct location of closure tags

Answer (score 0):

although you did not include where `parents('.thumbnail')` is located in the HTML markup, I still can guess what happen in your code.

what really happen is like this:

```
<div class="collection_swatches">         
    <a href="some-link-1" class="swatch">
        <span data-image="some-img-1" style="some-bg-img-css-1"></span>
    </a>

    <a href="some-link-2" class="swatch">
        <span data-image="some-img-2" style="some-bg-img-css-2"></span>
    </a>

    <a href="some-link-3" class="swatch">
        <span data-image="some-img-3" style="some-bg-img-css-3"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

when I click on the first `span`, `var link = $(this).parent().attr("href");` will result as `var link = 'some-link-1'`

next you check if the `span` has image on it, if it has, change the image on some `.thumbnail` container somewhere in the markup:

```
if($(this).data("image").indexOf("no-image") == -1) {
    $(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('img').attr('src', $(this).data("image"));
    $(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('img').attr('srcset', $(this).data("image"));
}
```

and then you change the link of an `<a>` in that container, which is does not mean the same `<a>` with the `var link` one

```
$(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('a').attr('href', link);
```

and you repeat that every click, therefore the call of `var link = $(this).parent().attr("href");` will result in the same link over and over, in this case it will result `'some-link-1'` all the time.

so what happen is that the click is triggered correctly, that is replacing a `href` of a link somewhere in your markup with the `href` of your parent `<a>`, and the replacement value is always the same.

**TLDR**: the logic of your code does not match with what you want it to be

**EDIT**:

okay, after your update, this confirms some points in Roman Habibi's answer, that is you changed the entire `<a>`'s `href`s below the `.thumbnail` container, as shown in your markup, the collection `spans`'s parents are located under `.thumbnail` container.

you can fix it by using `.first()` -- as the link you want to change is only the first one -- like this:

```
$(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('a').first().attr('href', link);
```

or using css selector:

```
$(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('a:first-of-type').attr('href', link);
```

Comment: I updated my question with markup, but this is a good step in the right direction I think. Although I thought using `this` on every click would replace the `href` attribute everytime, so I'm still a little confused there

Comment: I don't understand...why would it be the same everytime? when I console log `link` on every click it logs the correct link everytime?

Comment: what I meant is that when you click on the 1st `span` it will result `some-link-1` all the time, and the 2nd `span` would result `some-link-2` all the time, after your update I think I am getting of what you want to do, I'll try to re-analyze it.

Comment: Sort of...link updates nicely now, but image doesn't update

Comment: I COMPLETELY changed how I was going about this and it works now. I'm using `data-link` in the `<span>` tag and grabbing that which is working well.