# jQuery click event does not work - after form submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails Page View that is constructed like this:

```
script>

$('#carnum_driver_plus').click(function () {
    alert("click done");
});

</script>

....
<%= form_tag(.....(method: :post)) do %>

  <button id="carnum_driver_plus" type="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus align-text-bottom" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </button>

<% end %>
```

When I load this page the first time, the click handler worked and called the alert function. When I submit the form, it will be processed by a controller action, and then the same page view will be rendered. But then when I click the button again, nothing happened, the alert will not be called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('#carnum_driver_plus').click(function () {
    alert("click done");
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: ok, I never seen that. At which position I have to embed my js code ?

Comment: @SvenKirsten see edited answer. what version of Rails are you using?

Comment: rails version 5.1.4

Answer (score 0):

Try switching .click to .on()

```
$('#carnum_driver_plus').on('click', function() { 
//event handler...
}
```

Check out this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194728/jquery-click-event-works-only-once).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it does not help or fix the issue.

Comment: After reading your question again, I missed the part where you said it was after a post. How are you rendering the page view?

Comment: render(:page_view_name)